# jQuery filter elements based on data attribute

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a set of checkboxes and select list that are being used to filter elements.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="users">
  <input name="user" type="checkbox" value="1">
  John
  <input name="user" type="checkbox" value="2">
  Mike
  <input name="user" type="checkbox" value="3">
  Peter </div>

<select name="products">
  <option value="4">Product 1</option>
  <option value="5">Product 2</option>
  <option value="6">Product 3</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-filter="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-filter="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-filter="1">Item 3</li>
  <li data-filter="3">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

and here is javascript:

```
$('select[name=products]').change(function() {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    filterList(filter);
});

//News filter function
function filterList(value) {
    var list = $("#items li");
    $(list).fadeOut("fast");
    if (value == "all") {
        $("#items").find("li").each(function () {
            $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
        });
    } else {
        $("#items").find("li[data-filter*=" + value + "]").each(function () {
            $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is now to include checkboxes as well as part of filtering options, but I'm not sure which way to go. Do I coma separate data-filter values like: data-filter="1,3" where 1 is product, and 3 is user, or add new data attribute entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new code and solution. https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/p4w5zbyh/

Html - add class 'check' in the imputs

```
<div id="users">
  <input class="check" name="user" type="checkbox" value="1">
  John
  <input class="check" name="user" type="checkbox" value="2">
  Mike
  <input class="check" name="user" type="checkbox" value="3">
  Peter </div>

<select name="products">
  <option value="4">Product 1</option>
  <option value="5">Product 2</option>
  <option value="6">Product 3</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-filter="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-filter="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-filter="1">Item 3</li>
  <li data-filter="3">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('select[name=products]').change(function() {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    filterList(filter);
});

//News filter function
function filterList(value) {

    var checkedValue = new Array(); 

        var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
        for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue.push(inputElements[i].value);
      }
        }

      var list = $("#items li");
    $(list).fadeOut("fast");

    if (value == "all") {
          $("#items").find("li").each(function () {
            $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
        });
    } else {
        if(checkedValue.indexOf(value) < 0) {
            checkedValue.push(value);
        } 

        filter = new Array;

        checkedValue.forEach(function(entry) {
        filter.push("li[data-filter=" + entry + "]");

                });

        miVar1 = filter.join(",");
        console.log(miVar1);

            $("#items").find(miVar1).each(function () {
            $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
        });
    }
}
```

When you change select, read a checbox selecteds and set values in a array, and then, read value to *select products* and add value to array.
Then, the code

```
filter = new Array;
checkedValue.forEach(function(entry) {
    filter.push("li[data-filter=" + entry + "]");
});

miVar1 = filter.join(",");
```

create a new array with element filter and the concatenate array in string, example: "li[data-filter=1],li[data-filter=2],li[data-filter=4]" and use in the filter jquery.

Test jsfiddle and check browser console to see filter.

[image]

Comment: You can add event to click on the checkbox and execute function, read select option and checkbox values.

Comment: your jsfiddle does not work correctly for both products and users.

Comment: Why?? i test and work fine! check the console and see filter.. Or delete cache and try with jsfiddle. You understand the explication?

Comment: Or your select is AND?? If you check john (value 1) and select Product 2(value 5) you can see li with data-filter=1 or data-filter=5. If you need AND, the li attribute is bad, need use two attribute or conbine value, ex: user_product (1_5)

Comment: Its definatelly not working in Firefox, console shows an empty  string.

Comment: I Edited post  and added a image. The jsfiddle is the second. Work fine ;)

Comment: It only works if at least one checkbox are selected, but what I need for them to work independently. So that chackboxes and selects are both used as filtering option.

Comment: If you do not select boxes, filter with the select. 
To filter, is activated when the select changes. But It is not difficult to add the event to the boxes to activate filter, the code have the logic, I don't have time to make all.

Answer (score 2):

your select items are having different value, it should be like

```
<select name="products">
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-filter="1">Item 1</li>
 <li data-filter="2">Item 2</li>
 <li data-filter="3">Item 3</li>
 <li data-filter="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

for users, you have to make an array and put the checked values in that.
Then, on dropdown change you will call another function at end foreach values in the array. Some idea you can get from it.

```
 var selected = ['1','2'];
      $('selected').each(function (i) {
            $("#items").find("li[data-filter*=" + value + "]").each(function ()     {
            $(this).delay(200).slidedown("fast");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, select values are different then user values, so it will need to work both ways, using checkbox and select.